# Exception while trying to drop partition in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, partition

I have created a stored procedure to drop partitions. But I am getting following exception

> ORA-14126: only a  may follow description(s) of resulting partitions

```
create or replace procedure drop_a_partition(schema_name IN VARCHAR2, 
table_name IN VARCHAR2, partition_name IN VARCHAR2 ) as
BEGIN
  DECLARE
        lstatement VARCHAR(1000);
   BEGIN
        lstatement := 'ALTER TABLE '|| schema_name ||'.'|| table_name ||' 
        DROP PARTITION '|| partition_name ||' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' Executing ' || lstatement);
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lstatement;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'exception in drop_a_partition :  '
                               || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 500)
                              );
    END;


END;
END drop_a_partition;
/
```

Database version - 
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0.
I have looked around, but didn't see anything useful which would pinpoint to the exception. Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon after `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` causing this issue. I removed it. I am able to drop partition successfully.